# How to upload my package to the main in anaconda cloud

Tags: python, anaconda

Say I have a package I would like to distribute.

I can follow the instructions here to upload it to conda-forge, https://conda-forge.org.

But how do I upload to the default **main** repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - only Anaconda Inc. employees can develop and deploy builds there.  Alternatively, you can create an Anaconda user account and [deploy to an Anaconda Cloud user channel](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-cloud/user-guide/tasks/work-with-packages/#uploading-packages).  Then your package would be available through `conda install -c my_channel my_pkg`.

Comment: Could not find that answer anywhere!